# How to search effectively and fastly when we have 50,000 of JSON Data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, search

I have a json data like as follows

```
var data=[
{
Name: "AAA",
Phone : "1"
},
{
Name: "BBB",
Phone : "2"
},
|
|
|
|
|,
{
Name: "Z50000",
Phone : "50000"
}
]
```

I am searching for records that contains specific keyword (either name / phone). I am using javascript for that. I tried following way

```
var searchKeyword=document.getElementById("txtSearchKeyword").value;
var searchData=new Array();

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
if(data.Name.index(searchKeyword) !=-1 || data.Phone.index(searchKeyword) !=-1){
searchData.push(data[i]);
}
}
```

Everything is working fine, but it is taking a noticeable amount of time. How can search efficiently and fastly when we have big amound of data ?

Comment: Have you considered converting it to a JSON string and utilizing regex?

Comment: @Hayes that *might* be worth a try, but it seems unlikely that that would be faster, and certainly not easier; somehow the objects would have to be extracted from the string after being found.

Comment: I can't believe a regex would be faster on (a) a giant string, and (b) the backtracing necessary to get the data out.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just spit-balling with that one, but the results could be gathered via groups into a smaller collection.

Comment: Oh. What Pointy said.

Comment: Anyway the only real solutions to a problem like this involve building indexes, but if course that process itself would be time-consuming. Ideally it would be done in advance on the server; in fact this is a case where keeping the table in a real RDBMS and doing the searches via AJAX might end up being quicker. Mobile devices especially are going to be pretty slow doing all that work.

Comment: @Pointy: +1, though it doesn't have to be a *R* DBMS. A document database, maybe even one that deals natively with JSON, would fit as well

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what Hayes mentioned with utilizing regex, if your data is sorted (as it seems) you could use a binary search. This should run in O(log n) time but someone correct me if I'm wrong.

for example:

```
while not found 
    compare middle of data array with what you are searching
        if they match, return
        if what you are searching is > midpoint, call recursively on middle of last half
        else recursively call on middle of first half of array
```

Edit: turns out I misread the question. I'm leaving the code sample up in case someone find this in a google search and wants to search an array of jsons

Comment: Not exactly, because he's looking for entries *containing* the word.

Comment: Ah, I misread it then. It has to be O(n) because he has to check every single case to see if it contains the string. I thought he would be searching for a single object in the large set. This algorithm could be modified based on what he's searching/how it's ordered where this could possibly be more effective.